# How to replace inner string Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I have following code snippet,
The search criteria would be find all **img** tag that has **id="someImage"** value

```
<img id="someImage" src="C:\logo.png" height="64" width="104" alt="myImage" />
```

I want to replace

```
src="C:\logo.png" to src="someothervalue"
```

so the final output would be

```
<img id="someImage" src="C:\someothervalue" height="64" width="104" alt="myImage" />
```

How can i achieve this using regex.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with groups in a regex. You create groups by using parentheses in your regular expression. When you get a `Match` object, this object will contain a `Group` collection:

```
string input = "<html><img id=\"someImage\" src=\"C:\\logo.png\" height=\"64\" width=\"104\" alt=\"myImage\" /></html>";
var regex = new Regex("(<img(.+?)id=\"someImage\"(.+?))src=\"([^\"]+)\"");

string output = regex.Replace(
    input, 
    match => match.Groups[1].Value + "src=\"someothervalue\""
);
```

In the example above there will be 5 groups:

- `Groups[0]` This is the whole match: `<img id=\"someImage\" src=\"C:\\logo.png\"`
- `Groups[1]` This is everything before the `src` attribute: `<img id=\"someImage\"`
- `Groups[2]` and `Groups[3]` are the `(.+?)` parts.
- `Groups[4]` is the original value of the `src` attribute: `C:\logo.png`

In the example I replace the whole match for the value of `Groups[1]` and a new src attribute.

**Footnote**: While regular expressions can sometimes be adequate for the job to manipulate an html document, it is often not the best way. If you know in advance that you are working with `xhtml`, then you can use `XmlDocument` + `XPath`. If it is html, then you can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thanks for mentioning HtmlAgilityPack and for the answer, that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a good idea to use regex for XML. Depending on the language you should use some XML reader, extract the `<img>` node and then get its id. One useful language for querying XML data, which is supported by many XML libraries is XPath.

In C# you can look at [XmlDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument.aspx) class (and related classes).

Another one is [XmlReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlreader.aspx).

The latter offers only sequential access, while the first one loads the whole tree in memory, so the first one is easier to use (especially if your XML content is not too big).

Comment: Really? It looks like HTML to me. HTML is a special kind of XML.